# Compile JSP (check syntactical error in JSP)

Tags: java, jsp, syntax, error-handling, syntax-error

I have 1000 to 1200 [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) files in my project, and I want to check whether there is any syntactical error in those JSP files or not. So how can I check whether there are any error in JSP or not? Is there any way of compiling those JSPs?

Comment: Open them with any IDE and you should see the errors. But you need to think of opening 1000 to 1200!

Comment: Will I have to check for all 1200 JSPs !!!!

Comment: you can run them in the WebServer such as tomcat, and visit the url automatically

Comment: What would constitute a 'syntax error'? If you have that many JSPs, chances are that they will also include fragments of other JSPs and, while your JSP markup may be 'valid', the actual page returned to the user may not be. You may need to rethink what exactly you are trying to validate.

Comment: Is there anything like JSP compiler ?

Comment: some IDE's can show you some errors, but basically JSPs are compiled at runtime

Comment: They only solution is, pass them all. Later, fix the issues as they come.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every application server provides a copy of JSP pre-compilation tools. This utility translates the JSP into corresponding servlets `.java` files.

Some of them provide these tools as [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) tasks which you can use while building your web application using Ant. And some of them provide it as an executable which you have to run explicitly.

Look at the below for more information about these tools:

- [Tomcat JSP compiler](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.html)
- [WebLogic JSP compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/webapp/reference.html#57794)
- [Precompiling JSP files in WebSphere](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/trun_app_instwiz.html)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the application servers come with a JSP compiler that allows pre-compiling JSP files. The documentation of JspC, the Tomcat JSP compiler is in *[Jasper 2 JSP Engine How To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html)*. I also used WebLogic's JSP compiler in the past.

Note that, even if you don't use [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat), you could use this compiler just to check that your JSP files compile. If they compile with Tomcat, they should compile with your container.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) development, you can open JSP files with JSP EDIT. It's checking your JSP files for syntactical errors.

Comment: But the problem is I will have to open all JSPs, it is not possible

Comment: You only need to import your JSPs into eclipse as a project,then it will auto check ,if any jsp have syntectical error ,there will be a red cross on its name,so can you can find errors easy.

Comment: Will you please elaborate the process step by step ?

Comment: OK~.new a WEB Projece in your eclipse,in this project you can find a folder called 'WebRoot' ,then copy all JSPs to WebRoot folder.click Window--->Preferences--->General--->Editors--->Text Editors--->Spelling,make sure the 'Enable spelling checking' was checked . then wait a few mimutes，in eclipse Package Explorer ,if any jsp have syntectical error ,there will be a red cross on its name